# TypeError by writing data structure to XML file in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I would like to write a data structure into a XML file using Python with etree library. However, I got a `TypeError` with following message:

If I print the data structure in the command line, it looks fine. I'm not sure if this error is related to my XML file. I already executed the script with `python2` and `python3`.

```
root = ET.parse(args.filename).getroot()
taxi_root = ET.Element("routes")

for trip_tag in root.iter('trip'): 
    ET.SubElement(taxi_root, trip_tag)
    logging.warning(trip_tag, trip_tag.attrib)
    print(trip_tag, trip_tag.attrib)

taxi_tree = ET.ElementTree(taxi_root)
taxi_tree.write("taxi_trips.xml",xml_declaration=True)
```

The given XML file looks as follows:

```
<routes>
<trip id="randUni1151:1" type="random" depart="97.00" departPos="34.32" arrivalPos="45.48" arrivalSpeed="0.00" from="-319544709#1" to="25430299#5"/>
<trip id="randUni1922:1" type="random" depart="193.00" departPos="54.02" arrivalPos="134.49" arrivalSpeed="0.00" from="-166643442#0" to="60233456"/>
</routes>
```

I just want to write the data structure to a file, but I got this message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filter_Throughput_Traffic.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(ET.tostring(taxi_root, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8'))
  File "/Users/marius/.pyenv/versions/2.7.16/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1126, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(file, encoding, method=method)
  File "/Users/marius/.pyenv/versions/2.7.16/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 817, in write
    self._root, encoding, default_namespace
  File "/Users/marius/.pyenv/versions/2.7.16/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 886, in _namespaces
    _raise_serialization_error(tag)
  File "/Users/marius/.pyenv/versions/2.7.16/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1052, in _raise_serialization_error
    "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)
TypeError: cannot serialize <Element 'trip' at 0x103d4c750> (type Element)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works.
Look for the difference.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

xml = '''<routes>
<trip id="randUni1151:1" type="random" depart="97.00" departPos="34.32" arrivalPos="45.48" arrivalSpeed="0.00" from="-319544709#1" to="25430299#5"/>
<trip id="randUni1922:1" type="random" depart="193.00" departPos="54.02" arrivalPos="134.49" arrivalSpeed="0.00" from="-166643442#0" to="60233456"/>
</routes>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
tree = ElementTree(root)
tree.write('routes.xml')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found the mistake: In line 5
```ET.SubElement(traffic_root, "trip" ,trip_tag.attrib)```
did the job.